# How to replace while loop from Stored procedure using CLR proc C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, clrstoredprocedure

I want to replace the both While loops from the SP using CLR  Proc in C# can somebody help on this
We want to optimize the performance of the application some better thoughts are most welcomed
 thanks in advance
Here is my code snippet.

```
SET nocount ON

DECLARE @maxsize INT
DECLARE @x INT
DECLARE @starttime1 datetime
DECLARE @stoptime1 datetime
DECLARE @starttime2 datetime
DECLARE @stoptime2 datetime

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    [Alternate Name] VARCHAR(100),
    [Size] INT,
    [Creation Date] CHAR(8),
    [Creation Time] CHAR(6),
    [Last Written Date] CHAR( 8),
    [Last Written Time] CHAR(6),
    [Last Accessed Date] CHAR(8),
    [Last Accessed Time] CHAR(6),
    [Attributes] INT
    )

SET @x = 0 
SET @starttime1 = GETDATE()
WHILE @x < 20
    BEGIN 
    SET @x = @x + 1
    INSERT INTO #temp 
       EXEC master.dbo.tsql_getfiledetails_OLE 'C:\temp\longfilename.txt'
    END

SET @stoptime1 = GETDATE()
SET @x = 0 
SET @starttime2 = GETDATE()

WHILE @x < 20
    BEGIN 
    SET @x = @x + 1
    INSERT INTO #temp EXEC master.dbo.xp_getfiledetails 'C:\temp\longfilename.txt'
END

SET @stoptime2 = GETDATE()
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@starttime1, @stoptime1) ole_duration, 
    DATEDIFF(ms,@starttime2,@stoptime2) clr_duration 

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Stored procedure will usually be faster than doing things in code...

Comment: I concur with Dani, Stored Procedures execute directly in the context of SQL Server and aren't transmitting data over TCP with ADO.Net, as such are usually MUCH faster than doing it with code.  You'll be hard pressed to make any external code run faster than that SP.

Unless you build a SQL CLR Object that you register in SQL and call in the SP, then SQL Server will load the .net framework and execute your code in Process, in which case it will be pretty Speedy.

Comment: In my experience also, TSQL is always faster than CLR.  I only use CLR when I need to do something that just can't be done in TSQL.

Comment: @Ryios Thats fine its faster any help over how can we replace while from SP. Ryios